# How to perform arithmetic on the same line as a augmented assignment in Python 3.x.x?

Tags: python, arithmetic-expressions

In one of my programs,
I had the following line:

```
a = (a * b) + a
```

**Where a = 30, b = .05**
**This outputted 31.5 as the result**
This worked properly, but PyCharm told me I could turn it into an augmented assignment.

I know that  `a * = b` is the same as `a = a * b`

So I rewrote the line as follows:

`a *= b + a`

However upon compiling it **outputted the result of 901.5** which is obviously not the correct answer! Putting parenthesis anywhere does not change the result and I would like to do this in the same line as the augmented assignment instead of two separate lines, so in reality I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to get the augmented assignment to perform the same way as my initial equation on the same line?
2. If not, why can't we perform arithmetic on augmented assignments?

Comment: What about `a += a*b`?

Comment: @Lukasz R. I cannot believe I didn't think of using that! Wow I am stupid! HaHa, thank you very much! Thiers a reason I'm a noob at python....

Comment: When you write `a *= b+a`, you're evaluating `a = a * (b+a)`, which is 30(30.05) = 901.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
a += a * b
```

which will do `a * b` and then `+ a`, same result as:

```
a * b + a
```